# Preventing a specific function in a specific script from executing inside a browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, google-chrome-extension, adblock

Is it possible to prevent a specific function in a specific script from executing inside a browser, possibly by redirecting calls of that function to a static/modified version of the script file with a predefined rule? (Similar to how we use an adblocker extension or userscript to customize the DOM, but this time to manipulate the scripts themselves.)

Consider this scenario, `website.com` utilizes client-side rendering heavily. When `https://website.com/article.html` is visited, the bundled big JS file `https://website.com/entire-app.js` will render the entire webpage, both contents and ads.

In the end, a function named `isAdblockerFound()` in `https://website.com/entire-app.js` will be called by `antiAdBlockerMethod()` in the same script file. It checks if ads on the page are indeed loaded and performs other adblocker detection procedures. If this function returns `true`, `antiAdBlockerMethod()` will then trash and replace all the rendered elements in the DOM with some big warning text.

In this situation, the script `https://website.com/entire-app.js` handles all the client-side page rendering, both ads and contents, so simply blocking it from loading will render the website unaccessible.

In order to only bypass/fool the `isAdblockerFound()`, the idea I came up with is to somehow replace the `isAdblockerFound()` function with a function which always returns `false`, before it is called. That is, to tell the browser to redirect calls of `isAdblockerFound()` to a customized `isAdblockerFound()` in a static/modified version of the script file, hosted locally or resides temporarily in the browser.

I understand that if we don't need a predefined rule, we can use the devtools to freeze the script with a breakpoint and execute anything between lines easily. But how can we do this automatically with a predefined rule? What extensions/tools are needed?

Google didn't give me anything useful (all the results are about routing in express etc).

**EDIT**: I understand that I can disable my adblocker anytime and that would be a trivial solution for this question. I also understand why ads exist on the web in the first place, and appreciate the valuable contents made possible by ads. Actually I have never had motive to apply this to any websites I visit, and I am not aware of any websites employing adblocker checking procedures exactly like `website.com` in my example. I asked this question because I was simply curious if it is possible to bypass this kind of checking.

I suppose, in a different context, one website could be malicious and a security engineer would need to perform an analysis. He might find fooling an environment checking procedure useful in that scenario.

Comment: *"Is it possible to prevent a specific function in a specific script from executing using ad blocking extensions?"* No, that's not how ad blocker work. *"The idea I can come up with to prevent the page to be cleared up when an adblocker is found ..."* How about disabling the ad blocker for that page? Obviously you seem to value the content they produce, and they seem to appreciate an income for their work. Sometimes it's that simple

Comment: @Thomas Of course I can disable the adblocker anytime, and I understand the economics. Actually I have never had motive to apply this to any websites I visit. I asked because I peeked into the scripts of one of the website which used a mechanism similar to what I have described in my example. I was simply **curious** if it is possible to bypass that. In a different context, the website could be malicious and a security engineer were performing an analysis. He might find fooling an environment checking function useful in that scenario.

Comment: You can attack and bypass anything (in JS). The site, the whole code is running on your computer. Ultimately you have the entire control in what the page is doing. But ad blockers are not that sophisticated. They have enough to do, checking every single file request you make against a few thousand patterns.

Comment: *"He might find fooling an environment checking procedure useful in that scenario."* Sure. It's called the Developer Tools. Nowadays built into every browser. And as I said, you can check and manipulate everything that is executed while it is executed.

Comment: @Thomas Please see the updated question *"a predefined rule"*. Yes, I can manipulate everything, I do realize that I have physical access to my own computer, however not everyone programs with butterflies. Also you are welcome to write an answer instead of a comment to this question.

Comment: There is no real answer to this question. At least none more specific than the one I gave you, that you have full control over your computer. The topic is simply too vast. No, an adblocker can't prevent that specific function from being executed. But depending on how that function works you might be able to fool it by disabling some rules in you adblocker, or with an extension, or by an userscript, or, or, or .... it depends on what exactly this function does/how it works.

Comment: @Thomas Valid point, I'll see how I can rephrase the question. Maybe I could ask how to swap a specific function under a predefined rule, before any script is executed, like swapping the `isAdblockerFound()` with a one liner. Thanks.

Comment: It's most likely in some private context and you can't just replace the function. And again, adblocker/rules don't modify anything. They simply allow or reject a function to be loaded. You could use an extension to redirect the call to a static/modified version of the file, or to intercept the load and modify the file before it is parsed, but IMO that's way more complicated than figuring out what the function is missing (due to the adblocker) and mocking that.

Comment: @Thomas *"You could use an extension to redirect the call to a static/modified version of the file"* This sounds interesting. Just came back from google and didn't learn anything useful (all about routing in express etc). Could you elaborate on that, maybe as an answer to the updated question?     `isAdblockerFound()` actually comes from the very site inspired me to ask this question. I saw that script doing a lot of elements checking and if some elements are missing, it just removes everything. I have updated the question so it's not about adblockers/userscripts any more.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox provides the webextension API [webRequest.filterResponseData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/StreamFilter) to inspect and rewrite the content of any network request, including javascript loads. This would allow you to parse the javascript and replace the method in question.

That only leaves the task of building a robust, streaming javascript matching and rewriting engine.